# Easy way to extract flags from a string

Tags: python

I need a way to extract flags from a string and insert it into a dictionary.

For example, this string: `"--test arg1 arg2 --test2"` would be `{"test":"arg1 arg2", "test2":None}`. It should also work with `-` instead of `--`, so `"--test -test2 --test3 arg arg arg"`

I tried to use argparse, but I stopped using it as I didn't that it would call SystemExit.

I also tried to use `shlex.split(content)`, but it requires arguments to be in `''`, so I would still have to use a loop to change that.

Is there some module that can do this? I looked on pip and couldn't find something like this. But I know something has to exist like this.

Thanks!

Edit: second example should parse to `{"test":None, "test2":None, "test3": "arg arg arg"}`

Comment: What should your second example be parsed to?

Comment: Can you work with `argparser`?

Comment: Is your objection to argparse merely that is raises `SystemExit`? If so, you can catch that in a `try: ...  except SystemExit ...` structure and deal with it. Or is your objection that you don't want to predefine the allowed options? If so, argparse won't work so well.

Comment: The second example should be : {**"test"**:None, "test2":None, "test3": "arg arg arg"}, right?

Comment: @Megalng yep, my mistake

Comment: @FMc I don't want to specify the predefined flags, it should just parse all flags the user specifies, so argparse is not a good choice

Comment: @KremlaYour structure of string is same ? there would be - or -- always ?

Comment: @Ayodhyankit Paul It should accept both -- and - for the dictionary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `re` module:

```
import re
s = "--test -test2 --test3 arg arg arg -test4"

print({m.group(1): m.group(2) or None for m in re.finditer(r"--?(\w+)(?: ([^-]*)|$)", s)})
```

prints:

```
{'test': None, 'test2': None, 'test3': 'arg arg arg ', 'test4': None}
```

Explanation:

- `--?` One or two `-`
- `(\w+)` Any combination of word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) saved in the first group
- `(?: ([^-]*)|$)` a anonymous group consisting of either (`|`)

  - `([^-]*)` Any number of None `-` saved in the second group
  - `$` The end of the string ( In this case the second group is empty)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with "--test --test2", outputs: {'test': None} and not {'test': None, 'test2':None}

Answer (score 2):

You may use the function like below using regex to parse flags from string:

```
In [17]: def flag_parser(string):
    ...:     return {i[1]:i[2].strip() if i[2].strip() else None for i in re.findall(r'(-{1,2})(\w+) ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)', string)}
    ...: 

In [18]: flag_parser("--test -test2 --test3 arg arg arg")
Out[18]: {'test': None, 'test2': None, 'test3': 'arg arg arg'}
```

Explanation of regex:

```
re.findall(r'(-{1,2})(\w+) ([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)', string)
```

`re.findall` - finds and returns list of all the matched item.

`(-{1,2})` - one or two occurrence of `-`

`(\w+)` - match a word of length one or more

`([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)` - match arguments

Comment: Issue with this: flag_parser("--test --test2") returns {'test': None} and not {'test': None, 'test2':None}

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with split:

```
mystring = '--test arg1 arg2 --test2 --test3 arg1'

mydict = {}

for x in mystring.split('--'):
    if 'test' in x.split(' ')[0]:
        mydict[x.split(' ')[0]] = ''.join(x.split(' ')[1:])

print(mydict)

#output

{'test': 'arg1 arg2 ', 'test2': '', 'test3': 'arg1'}
```